# C#, Winforms, Dataset, switching between TableAdapters.Fill method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a common dataset in which there are several TableAdapter and DataTable. Gridcontrols(5-6) shows ready datasource. There are two large tables: Inbox (16000 Records) and outgoing (6000 entries). When switching

```
view_all_outbox_doctableadapter.Fill(this.delodataset.View_all_outbox_doc);
view_all_inbox_doctableadapter.file(this.delodataset.View_all_inbox_doc);
```

From incoming documents the program hangs for 5-15 seconds, in the loaded time even more. I noticed that when switching from large records to small recordings the program hangs, but on the contrary, there is no. I realized that loading TableAdapter first frees the loaded memory and then loads the new data. I even tried to use code which call runtime another dataset:

```
String connectionString = Settings.Default.deloconnectionstring;
String storedprocedurename = "Getoutboxdoc ";
DataSet ds = new DataSet ("Outbox");
Try
{
    using (SqlConnection Sqlcon = new SqlConnection (connectionString))
    {
        Sqlcon.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (StoredProcedureName, Sqlcon);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        DataAdapter.Fill(DS);
        Gridcontrol5.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

The results have not changed. What you need to do to make sure that the program is not hung up.

Comment: In what line of code does the delay occur?

Comment: solved, problem was in tabs when i swich i set visibility false to some tabs. solve in other way